# Serial.readString() not working becaue of outdated IDE?

Tags: serial

I've searched google honestly but can't find an answer nor changelogs for Arduino that might be the answer.

Basically I'm trying to use Serial.readString() to input commands to the Serial Monitor but it shows an error that readString is not a member of 'HardwareSerial'.

I am using Arduino 1.0 as IDE because the device I'm using (Aceduino) seems to have a custom IDE derived from 1.0 so I'm not sure if it will work with newer IDE versions. Wondering if that was what's causing the eror

Answer (score 1):

`Stream::readString()` is available since version 1.0.1. See:

- the [changelog](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/revisions.txt#L1038), and
- the [corresponding commit](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/commit/39eed5a).